# Script to search Xcode project for OS specific selectors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, backwards-compatibility

I've produced a project that runs fine on iOS 8 (there are no unit tests though). It's a rather large project, and I don't have time to test all the features on a different operating system. I however, want to determine whether it would run with the same stability on iOS 7.

Of course, there are plenty of reasons that it wouldn't aside from the fact of using iOS 8 specific methods, however I've had a google for a script or process that would have:

```
functionality to determine whether my Xcode project has iOS 8 specific methods, and if so, where.
```

For instance, this method has tripped me up before:

```
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

Is there anyway of pulling all the method declaration information, and the OS availability of it, and then using that to parse the current Xcode project to determine whether I'm using code that will only run on iOS 8?

Or is this an impossible ask?

Comment: Maybe the breaking changes docs are not sufficient? I agree this would be a great thing, but I'm not familiar enough with Apple's release notes procedure to know where you would find the info.

Comment: I had in mind some way of running scripts through all the header files in the  Apple frameworks and then collating all the 'NS_AVAILABLE()' information for each method and subsequently comparing this to the project source code to match availabilities? I was hoping that existed, but apparently not!

Comment: It seems like even getting the frameworks headers themselves is a little trouble, due to the hierarchies, but someone wrote zshell script it seems [1]. I wonder if other languages are better at this problem? 
1.[] ; ; ; ; ; X.The Grey Blog: How to Include Apple Frameworks' Headers in C/C++ Projects in IDEs Lacking Proper Support such as Eclipse CDT and NetBeans ; ; http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-include-apple-frameworks-headers.html

Comment: To be fair, most of the issues stem from the much more widely used methods declared in Foundation.framework and UIKit.framework which don't contain header subdirectories. Writing a script to run through all the headers found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/... should work, and it could also look through sub-directories too come to think of it. It could then build the model and subsequently run the .xcodeproj directory through it to find methods that aren't backwards compatible.

Comment: I could give it an attempt in perl later actually, it works in theory at least (I think)